# returning the word if it is of certain length in python

Tags: python

I am writing code in which a word list is inputted. If any of the words in the list are of exactly 4 characters then those words will be returned in this format:

['word','four']

I am making a loop to check the whole list but obviously return is stopping the function so only the first 4 letter word is getting printed. As per instructions 'return' must be used and not print and the output must be in the list format like above. any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
    def letter(list):
        word = []
        for word in list:
            if len(word)==4:
                return word
```

Comment: Also, take a look at `yield`, for an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once `return` is used it exits from the function so its better to populate an entire list of four letter words an then return it

```
def letter(word_list):
    words = []
    for word in word_list:
        if len(word)==4:
            words.append(word)
    return words
```

Comment: i guess it's return words

Comment: Or more pythonic: `return [word for word in _list if len(str(word)) == 4]` (list replaced with _list because it's a reseved identifier)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using the built-in filter function that takes a boolean function and an iterable as inputs. For filter(f(item), lst) returns all items in lst for which f(item) returns true. Keep in mind that filter() returns a filter object, so you need to apply list(filter()) to return the list. For this case, the code would be:

```
    list(filter(lambda word: len(word) == 4, words))
```

Another way to do it would be to use a list comprehension:

```
    [word for word in words if len(word) == 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension

```
def letter(list):
    return [word for word in list if len(word)==4]
```

Comment: try letter([1234]) and see what happens (hint: `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`) - It's not required by the question but better use it - just in case it gets used with integers too

Comment: The function is intended for use with strings. An error is better than returning len(str(word)), which would produce a misleading result.